# openFile - permission denied - when reading and writing to the same file

Tags: file, haskell, io, lazy-evaluation

I have an error 'openFile - permission denied' when I try write something to file:

```
saveFile content path = do
        writeFile path (show content)
```

why ?

Comment: Check your `path`, you probably really do not have permission.

Comment: I have full control on this file :/

Comment: Your OS seems to think otherwise.  Did you previously open this file with `readFile`?  If so, try to close the handle before opening it again with `writeFile`.

Comment: yes - I have: loadFile path = do x <- readFile path return (read x) - so what is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your questions, it appears that you're using `readFile` and `writeFile` from `System.IO` on the same file.

Remember that [`System.IO.readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:readFile) is *lazy*, meaning that the file handle is opened, initially, and then as your program requires data, pieces will be read. Only once all data has been read, or all references to the file dropped, will the file handle be closed. Until then the *resource is locked*.

You need to ensure the file is read fully before trying to write to it, or otherwise closed the file in some way. A simple way to achieve this is to use strict IO. E.g,:

```
loadFileStrict :: Read a => FilePath -> IO a
loadFileStrict f = do
    s <- readFile f
    length s `seq` return s
```

Here, we ask for the length of the string, before returning the result. This forces the entire contents to be read.

This pattern is captured in the [strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict) package.